# dp differences between Nexus5 and Nexus5X?

Tags: android, pixel-density

I defined this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSmartphone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_smartphone_data" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivData1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivSmartphone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_data_1" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivData2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ivData1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_data_2" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivData3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ivData2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_data_3" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivData4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ivData3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_data_4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It should looks like this one according to the android studio preview window:
[image: designer preview]

On a Nexus5X it looks exactly like this, but on a Nexus5 i get
[image]

I thought Nexus5X and Nexus5 have the same density and take [the images from the same xxhdpi directory](https://design.google.com/devices/)? So what's missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will get this difference because Nexus 5 density is 3 and Nexus 5X density is 2.6

Answer (score 1):

The size of the Nexus 5 is 360x640dp while the one of the Nexus 5X is 411x731dp while having the same density.

So when you define you layout like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSmartphone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_smartphone_data" />
```

you're using the same image for every screen width without scaling. Instead you need to make sure to fit your images to the screen width.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSmartphone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCentered"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_smartphone_data" />
```

`fitCentered` might also upscale the image. If you're fine with a bigger spacing consider using `centerInside` instead.